# Formal Parameter error with Rest operator

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to use the rest operator to allow a function to take an unknown number of arguments, but no matter how simple my function I get a Missing formal parameter error. Here's an example of one of the functions I tried:

```
function Rental(name, ...bikes) {
   //..
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are calling/using the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAS is [based on javascript 1.6](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features) which means that it doesn't support the spread operator.
You'll have to resort back to old-school tricks:

```
function Rental() {
  var name = arguments[0];
  var bikes = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you! I wondered about that but it was surprisingly hard to find which version GAS runs on